How to Persist Offset for Custom Source with Flink Datasource API?
I'm developing a custom source for Apache Flink 1.18 and need to ensure that the offset for each partition is correctly persisted and restored between pipeline restarts. I can't store the offset in the data source system, so it needs to be correctly checkpointed within Flink. I'm confused about the separation between SourceSplit and SplitState.

Should the current offset be stored in the SourceSplit or the SplitState?
Does Flink persist the split state, including offsets, during checkpoints?

Any clarification or examples would be greatly appreciated.
data class CustomSourceSplit(
    val partition: Int
) : SourceSplit {
    override fun splitId(): String {
        return partition.toString()
    }
}

data class CustomSourceSplitState(
    val split: CustomSourceSplit,
    var offset: Long // Current processing offset within the split
)


